# How to correctly use Siege to benchmark GET requests?

Tags: linux, web-services, http, benchmarking

I use siege to benchmark a local HTTP service:

```
siege -q -b -t 30S -c 64 "http://localhost:8888/endpoint?params=abc"
```

Benchmark result gives ~500 transactions per second throughput.

However, when I benchmark the service manually by launching 8 simultaneous loops of `curl`, the same endpoint gives many thousands per second throughput.

So what am I doing wrong with siege?

Comment: Maybe curl reuse the same TCP  session or does things like HTTP pipelining.

Comment: Hey, I think the actual reason for this is that someting in siege is implemented very inefficiently: When its config setting `chunked = true` (default) is set, requests take really long and max out a CPU core at 100%. When I set `chunked = false`, it's as fast as `wget` and `curl`. I think this is an error in `siege` because `wget` also uses chunked encoding by default and it's not slow.

Could you try whether setting `chunked = false` fixes it for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a few things that may be impacting your test.  Check to see what you get if you set concurrent `-c` to 8 to match the number of concurrents you are testing with curl.  Your site may not be able to handle a high number of concurrent users.

Also Siege by default does not do keep alive (I don't think at least).  By not using this option the server and client have to set up and tear down sockets which can be costly.  You should be able to set the header and have it honored (`siege -H "Connection: Keep-Alive"`).

As a side note, I find it useful to use several tools when benchmarking, once you get siege working, i'd play with AB (apache bench), httperf and keep your manual curl testing around as well.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, I am disappointed with siege, now switching to httperf.

Comment: Is there any rule that siege uses to make connections when `Keep-Alive` is enabled? I mean how many HTTP transaction will pass through every connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull it off on the command-line using bash process substitution to create a dynamic siegrc file:

```
siege -R <(echo connection = keep-alive) ...
```